# Display input type of checkbox and label on the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm learning to use html and css by doing a simple web. I'm trying to put the input checkbox and the text on the same line using display grid. It seem on the same line in the code snippet below, but on edge, it doesn't feel right. Does someone have any suggestions for me? Thank you so much!

[image: display on my laptop]

```css
.improve {
  margin: 20px 150px 40px 345px; 
}

.ans {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 250px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="improve">
          <label for="improve">What would you like to see improved? (Check all that apply)</label>
          <div class="ans">
            <input type="checkbox" id="fe" value="Front-end Projects"> 
            <label for="fe">Front-end Projects</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="be" value="Back-end Projects"> 
            <label for="be">Back-end Projects</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="da" value="Data Visualization"> 
            <label for="da">Data Visualization</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ch" value="Challenges"> 
            <label for="ch">Challenges</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="os" value="Open Source Community"> 
            <label for="os">Open Source Community</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="help" value="Gitter help rooms"> 
            <label for="help">Gitter help rooms</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="vid" value="Videos"> 
            <label for="vid">Videos</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="meet" value="City Meetups"> 
            <label for="meet">City Meetups</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="wiki" value="Wiki">
            <label for="wiki">Wiki</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="forum" value="Forum"> 
            <label for="forum">Forum</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="add" value="Additional Courses"> 
            <label for="add">Additional Courses</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By wrapping the whole input field inside the label, you can use flexbox on the label, to make sure everything is centered. This also allows the user to click on the label text, to check the checkbox (well, the `for` attribute already does that).

```css
.ans {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ans > label {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
       <div class="improve">
          <label for="improve">What would you like to see improved? (Check all that apply)</label>
          <div class="ans">
            <label for="fe">
              <input type="checkbox" id="fe" value="Front-end Projects"> 
              Front-end Projects
            </label>
            <label for="be">
              <input type="checkbox" id="be" value="Back-end Projects"> 
              Back-end Projects
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
```